# Mobx Observable Array not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am declaring a observable array in the following way in reactjs using mobx

```
@observable cacheditems

constructor() {
    this.cacheditems  =   []
```

Now I am retrieving the data from pouch-db when offline as follows:

```
var items = []
db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, function(err, docs) {
                docs.rows.map((obj, id) => {
                    items.push(obj.doc)
                })
            })


 this.cacheditems = items
```

But the data is not set. When I try to get the data for rendering its a empty array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `this.cacheditems = items` you are overwriting the reference to the observable array. You can use [**replace**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) instead:

```
class Store {
  @observable cacheditems = []

  constructor() {
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, (err, docs) => {
      var items = []
      docs.rows.map((obj, id) => {
        items.push(obj.doc)
      })
      this.cacheditems.replace(items)
    })
  }
}
```